# Bollinger Band shading not shading in colour

Tags: python, matplotlib, stock

I am trying to shade between the upper red line and the lower orange line which represent the 'upper band' and 'lower band'

I have gotten to this image:

[image]

The code I have tried is as follows:

```
    fig = plt.figure()
    plt.plot(dataset[['Adj Close', 'ma21', 'upper_band', 'lower_band']])
    plt.fill_between(dataset.index, dataset['upper_band'], dataset['lower_band'], color='grey',  alpha = 0.3)
    plt.legend(loc='best')
    plt.savefig('bollinger.png')
    plt.show()
```

I believe it has something to do with the `dataset.index` but i am unsure how to get the x-axis correctly.

Thanks.

Comment: The problem seems to be that you use the index for `plt.fill_between`, but no index for `plt.plot`. Try using `plt.fill_between(range(len(dataset)), dataset['upper_band'], dataset['lower_band'], ...)` to make both plots using the same x-axis.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the documentation found [here](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/fill_between_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-fill-between-demo-py) and by using the `matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between` method

Here is an example of it being used:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(0.0, 2, 0.01)
y1 = np.sin(2 * np.pi * x)
y2 = 0.8 * np.sin(4 * np.pi * x)

fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(3, 1, sharex=True, figsize=(6, 6))

ax3.fill_between(x, y1, y2)
ax3.set_title('fill between y1 and y2')
ax3.set_xlabel('x')
fig.tight_layout()
```

Comment: excellent. have you tried using the fill_between command?